# H2 console does not show up

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, h2

I've read almost all the questions with H2 console but did not find a solution. I am getting **Whitelabel Error Page** when I hit the URL `http://localhost:8080/h2-console`.

I have added below dependencies in my project:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.h2database/h2 -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

*application.properties*

```ini
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

[image: Whitelabel Error Page]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add this in *application-properties*

```
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
```

---

properties for H2

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console
```

*DB_CLOSE_DELAY = -1 is prevents the connection lost*

---

**UPDATE**

For Spring Boot 2.x straight from Spring Initialzr:

Default with devtools is `http://127.0.0.1:8080/h2-console/`

*POM: spring-boot-starter, h2, spring-boot-starter-web, spring-boot-devtools*

Without devtools - you need to set it in properties:

`spring.h2.console.enabled=true spring.h2.console.path=/h2-console`

*POM: spring-boot-starter, h2, spring-boot-starter-web*